# I want to retrieve remote provisioning template from SharePoint library and then provision it using pnp framework 1.12.0 to a client tenant

Tags: sharepoint, .net-6.0, pnp-framework

I'm working on a .NET6 web api, and i use the pnp framework in order to provision remotely SharePoint templates to client tenant, for the templates i store them in a SharePoint library and i want to access them.

i tried this code for that but i got an error on GetTemplate("PnPProvisioningDemo.xml") method: **The Provisioning Template URI PnPProvisioningDemo.xml is not valid**.  i tried to search in documentation but nothing found.

is there another way to load template from sharepoint library or fix the current issue, Thank you.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("https://11h33g.sharepoint.com"))
            {
                context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    args.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                };
                // Load the template from the SharePoint library

                var provider = new XMLSharePointTemplateProvider(context, "https://11h33g.sharepoint.com/sites/devanddep", "Documents");

                ProvisioningTemplate template = provider.GetTemplate("PnPProvisioningDemo.xml");

                // Apply the template to the SharePoint site
                ctx.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);

                

            }
```